# Nested namespace in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces, activeadmin

I need to have a nested namespace:

/admin/namespace/resource.rb*

I'd like to know how I could create this through ruby (`rails g active_admin:resource namespace/Resource` didn't work)

Are any additions to routes.rb? possibly like the following:

```
namespace "admin" do
   namespace "namespace" do
      resources :resources
   end
end
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

- just an example

Answer (score 0):

you can define the namespace in the ActiveAdmin Registration, but I'm not sure if it even works with nested Namespaces ..

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project, :namespace => :sales do
  # this resource is generates in namespace /sales
end
```

Comment: This will not generate `admin/sales/projects` | I think the solution will be to keep it in route.rb.